# Error on X Server Version when installing amd graphic driver ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 18.04, amd-graphics

I have downloaded run file from amd website to install my graphic driver on ubuntu 18.04 x64. I ran it from command line and it give me this error :

```
Detected X Server version 'XServer _64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib:XServer _64a:none:4.15.0-23-generic:)
```

Comment: What run file, from which website? did you read [BinaryDriverHowto/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

Comment: graphic driver installation .run file, from AMD Website.
Yes I read that, I thought it was for Ubuntu 14.04 only :(

Comment: Any solution on this?  I'm having this problem now as well